# Display the tuition for each student based on their grade average and attendance

Tags: php

Right so just for clarification,most of these variables and arrays aren't in English so I'll provide rough tranlations for easier readability:

kontroliniai = tests(with their Student names and then grades for various tests) 
stipendija = tuition
lankomumas = attendance

Ok so what I want to achieve is change the tuition value based on how the conditionals interpret the grades in the array

but all I get in the whole page is just 80 when I was atleast hoping it would output all three tuitions,anyway here's the code:

the array:

```
<?php
$mokiniai = array("Jonas" => array(
    "AK" =>"30012075412",
    "Vardas"=>"Jonas",
    "Pavarde"=>"Jonelis",
    "Ep"=>"JJonelis@gmail.com"),
    "Jolanta"=> array(
        "AK" =>"40011175612",
        "Vardas"=>"Jolanta",
        "Pavarde"=>"Joliene",
        "Ep"=>"JoJoiene@gmail.com"),
    "Dovydas"=> array(
        "AK" =>"399011175692",
        "Vardas"=>"Dovydas",
        "Pavarde"=>"Pavardenis",
        "Ep"=>"Dovadenis@gmail.com")
    );
$kontroliniai = array("Jonas" => array(
  "Matematika"=>9,
"Lietuviu"=> 5,
    "Anglu"=>7),
    "Jolanta"=> array(
        "Matematika"=>10,
        "Lietuviu"=> 7,
        "Anglu"=>7  ),
    "Dovydas"=> array(
        "Matematika"=>6,
        "Lietuviu"=> 8,
        "Anglu"=>10)
);
$lankomumas = array("Jonas" => array(
   "praleista pam :"=>5),
    "Jolanta"=> array(
        "praleista pam :"=>2 ),
    "Dovydas"=> array(
        "praleista pam :"=>6 )
);
```

the array interpreter:

```
<?php
include 'duomenys.php';
$stipendija=1;

foreach($kontroliniai as $key => $grades) {

    $average = array_sum($grades) / count($grades);

    //echo results
    if ($average > 8) {
       $stipendija = 100;

    } elseif ($average>=5 && $average<=8){
        $stipendija = 80;
    }
    else{
        $stipendija = 0;
    }
}
foreach($lankomumas as $key => $skaicius) {

    if($skaicius>=2 && $skaicius<=10){
    $stipendija = $stipendija - ($stipendija*10/100);
    }
    else{
    $stipendija *0;
    }}
    echo $stipendija;
```

Comment: You're overwriting your `$stipendija` variable every time you iterate through the first `foreach` loop.  You need to figure out a better way to store the results (another array?) so you don't keep replacing the value in that variable with another.  Put another way: your comment says `//echo results`, yet, instead of echoing, you're merely assigning.

Comment: I was under the assumption if the condition is fulfilled I can just change the tuition value and move on

Comment: Hypothetical example: Loop 1: $average > 8, so $stipendija = 100.  Loop 2, $average < 5, so *the same $stipendija variable* now = 0.  You need to do something more to store the $stipendija values, because, again, you're overwriting that one variable every element of $kontroliniai you have.